# PHP 5.4.19 running in terminal & PHP 5.3.26 on my localhost, how to switch localhost version?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

I just installed PHP 5.4.19 on my os X 10.6.8 Mac using homebrew. I was previously using PHP 5.3.26 probably installed with MacPorts.

If I type `php -v` in terminal, I get PHP 5.4.19. If I load a `phpinfo()` file through my localhost I get PHP 5.3.26. How do instruct Apache to load my new installation of PHP?

If I run `php --ini`, I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
```

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file has this setting:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so
```

I have tried changing the LoadModule in my httpd.conf file to:

`/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`,

but I get an error which reads:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 118 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/libcurl.4.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open your Apache2 config file in terminal:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/apache2/httpd-conf
```

End hit `ctrl + w` to search `libphp5.so`. After found its line, put `#` beginnig of the line to  make it disable. So, here is the last view:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

After restart your apache by running `sudo apachectl graceful`, localhost will recognize PHP 5.4 as default version.

Comment: your solution actually worked in a round-about way! I commented out "#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so" then restarted. This turned off php - (if I loaded a php file in my browser, it just printed out as code). I then went back to my httpd.conf file and uncommented the full path to the homebrew libphp5.so file (as I tried before in the above question) and restarted. This time, it worked!  I'm not sure why!

Answer (score 1):

My PHP version running in terminal was 5.3 and localhost shows 5.4. But after I tried the failed way from the first post, I was able to sync the php version on both environments.

Just simply reload the php5_module

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.28/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well brew and ports play together, but perhaps you should be using brew install of both apache2 and PHP.